# How can I find out which user placed an item into a queue in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I checked audit history and was unable to find any relevant information regarding when/who placed the item into the queue.

[Dynamics 365 CRM // Email Container]

[EDIT] I found out you can obtain this information via the "Created By" field.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by queue and for which product and version you are asking the question? You tagged the question with the tags of three distinct products in the Dynamics 365 product family.

Comment: See edits, this has been solved using the "Created By" field.

Comment: Consider adding this information as an answer so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I found out you can obtain this information via the "Created By" field.